# XNA C# Mario Collide

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to make Mario so im trying to do the collision part but whenever I do the side collision it bounces back too far. I want to make it so that it only stops Mario not bounces him back.

```
        public void MarioBrickCollide()
    {
        for (int collide = 0; collide < brick.Length; collide++)
        {
            if (Mariovec.Y <= brickvec[collide].Y && Mariovec.Y + Mario.Height + 3 > brickvec[collide].Y && Mariovec.X + Mario.Width > brickvec[collide].X && Mariovec.X < brickvec[collide].X + brick[collide].Width)
            {
                Mariovel.Y = 0;
                brickHitTop = true;
            }
            if (Mariovec.X + Mario.Width >= brickvec[0].X && Mariovec.X < brickvec[0].X + brick[0].Width && Mariovec.Y + Mario.Height > brickvec[0].Y && Mariovec.Y < brickvec[0].Y)
            {
                Mariovec.X = brickvec[collide].X - Mario.Width;
            }
        }
    }
```

What can I do to make the collisions work?

Answer (score 1):

Formatted your code so I can read it:

```
public void MarioBrickCollide() {
   for (int collide = 0; collide < brick.Length; collide++) {
      if (Mariovec.Y <= brickvec[collide].Y
         && Mariovec.Y + Mario.Height + 3 > brickvec[collide].Y
         && Mariovec.X + Mario.Width > brickvec[collide].X
         && Mariovec.X < brickvec[collide].X + brick[collide].Width
      ) {
         Mariovel.Y = 0;
         brickHitTop = true;
      }

      if (Mariovec.X + Mario.Width >= brickvec[0].X
         && Mariovec.X < brickvec[0].X + brick[0].Width
         && Mariovec.Y + Mario.Height > brickvec[0].Y
         && Mariovec.Y < brickvec[0].Y
      )
         Mariovec.X = brickvec[collide].X - Mario.Width;
    }
}
```

should the `0` indexes in the second `if` statement actually be `collide` instead?

Comment: This looks more like an edit and a comment than an answer.